# Thucydides not respecting browser specified in pom.xml for project built from thucydides-jbehave-archetype

Tags: webdriver, thucydides

I have a project built from the [thucydides-jbehave-archetype](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22thucydides-jbehave-archetype%22)

I'm trying to follow these steps to change the browser that Thucydides is running with when I run my projectL  http://thucydides.info/docs/thucydides/_running_thucydides_in_different_browsers.html

In the pom.xml I had this (which is from the thucydides archetype):

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and per the instructions, I have changed this to:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <!-- 
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
             -->
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

and I also changed the value in my properties section:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <thucydides.version>0.9.205</thucydides.version>
    <thucydides.jbehave.version>0.9.205</thucydides.jbehave.version>
    <!-- I have tried chrome too -->
    <webdriver.driver>safari</webdriver.driver>
</properties>
```

but my tests are still running with the default browser (firefox).  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with systemPropertyVariables and I've decided don't use pom.xml for this.

You need to create class *TestSuite and to extend it from class ThucydidesJUnitStories. 
In constructor you just set properties which you need.

```
import net.thucydides.core.ThucydidesSystemProperty;
import net.thucydides.jbehave.ThucydidesJUnitStories;
```

public class PremiumTestSuite extends ThucydidesJUnitStories {

`public PremiumTestSuite() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.home") + "/chromedriver");

    getSystemConfiguration().setIfUndefined("webdriver.driver", "chrome");
    getSystemConfiguration().setIfUndefined(ThucydidesSystemProperty.THUCYDIDES_STORE_HTML_SOURCE.getPropertyName(), "true");
    getSystemConfiguration().setIfUndefined(ThucydidesSystemProperty.THUCYDIDES_TAKE_SCREENSHOTS.getPropertyName(), "FOR_FAILURES");
    }
}`

I hope it will help you :)